# How to display the same date in fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make an event that will last 3 days or more have the same schedule, but I'm not getting it right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoT5R.png)

As you can see in the image what fullcalendar is doing is setting 16:00 - 00:00 and 00:00 - 18:00.

What I need to achieve is to make it 16:00 - 18:00, for the 3 days.

The project is being done under PHP, CodeIgniter, Javascript and Mysql.

**Return Json result for codeigniter 4**

```
public function MostrarEventos()
{
    # - Llamo al modelo de ventanas
    $ventanasModel = model('VentanasModel');

    return json_encode($ventanasModel->findAll());
}
```

**DB Table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvo60.png)

Full Calendar Code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

let formulario = document.querySelector("form");

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    // Arranca del mes
    // initialView: 'timeGrid',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',

    // Idioma del calendario
    locale: 'es',

    // Franja Horaria
    slotDuration: '04:00', // 4 hours
    minTime: "11:00",
    maxTime: "20:00",

    // Cabecera del calendario
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'dayGridMonth timeGridWeek listWeek',
        center: 'title',
        // right: 'prev, next today',
    },

    // events: "http://webmsg.local.com/ventanas/MostrarEventos",

    // nextDayThreshold: '09:00:00',
    eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ag/viewAg', // use the `url` property
          color: 'orange',    // an option!
          textColor: 'black',  // an option!
        }
      ],

      eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false
    },

    dateClick: function (info) {
        $('#evento').addClass("is-active");
    }

});

calendar.render();

// Capturo la accion del boton
document.getElementById("btnGuardar").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const datos = new FormData(formulario);
    // console.log(datos);
    // console.log(formulario.title.value);

    // Envio los datos por post
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1/ag/saveAg", datos).
        then(
            (respuesta) => {
                $('#evento').removeClass("is-active");
            }
        ).catch(err => {
            if (err.response) {
                console.log(err.response.data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: `What I need to achieve is to make it 16:00 - 18:00, for the 3 days.`... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events

Comment: @ADyson It is not what I am looking for, since this method is for every day and what I need is for specific dates.

Comment: `since this method is for every day and what I need is for specific dates.`...that's not true, please read the documentation again. You can specify which days of the week it occurs on, and when it starts and ends. However if you need even more detailed control over the recurrence, then see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin instead.

Comment: @ADyson What I mean is that I need to select a date from to a date up to e.g. August 5 to August 10, all on the same schedule.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what recurring events does.

Comment: Here's a really simple example: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYwWwyV

Comment: @ADyson I understand, but if I have events until the 31st, the 31st would not be listing them for me since it ends on the end.

Comment: Well the documentation does mention that the end date is exclusive (this is the same behaviour as for events themselves). All you need to do is add an extra day onto it when you're creating the JSON.